# How to handle the concurrence of file uploads in my kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am designing the architecture of my software instance provisioning system. For this I will use kubernetes in such a way that each client will have their namespace with the pods of their integrity. However, the kubernetes cluster will have a common entry point to all the instances, which will be a nginx server.

My question is as follows, as software provided allows upload of files, in case at the same time several of my clients decide to upload a file simultaneously, I run the risk that the server nginx is overloaded and that nobody can access your instance hired?

Is there any good practice to try to design my architecture?

Comment: I guess you're also thinking of autos along the cluster and putting resource limits on each namespace to prevent any one client from using most of the cluster's resources

Comment: Ryan's answer is one option (scaling the entry point). Another option would be to use istio and based on headers send to the correct deployment

Answer (score 1):

You could use [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md) and deploy it with multiple replicas so that it can be scaled up to handle the load. Then your nginx is part of the cluster (rather than a separate server) and can take advantage of the kubernetes cluster's capacity for horizontal scaling.

Unless you are running on-prem with NodePort/HostPort - then you might want to run your nginx as an external Load balancer as in that case you don't have one from a cloud provider. Then what you can do is configure rate-limiting and throttling in nginx. If cloud then you can also use annotations to do this with nginx ingress.